# connect segue to Navigation control

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

Before I used a Segue to transfer data between to view controllers.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Edit List" {
        if let currentTodo = todoReadyForEditing, let editControler = segue.destination as? ListPageController {
            editList.prepare(for: currentList)
        }
```

Now the plan is changed I should transfer the data from the first view controllers to a `tableViewController`. Since I want to have a navigation bar to the `tableViewController` page, I added a `navigationBarController` before it.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Edit List" {
        if let currentTodo = todoReadyForEditing, let editControler = segue.destination as? ListTableViewController {
            editList.prepare(for: currentList)
        }
```

The problem is when I connected segue directly to UITableViewController, everything is work, same as before that I have two view controllers, but the navigation bar is hidden, which I don't want. As I read, apparently i have to connect the segue first to the navigationViewController, but when I did not, the data won't transfer to the table view controller.

Is there any suggestion? Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destination of segue is `UINavigationController`, but you can work with its `topViewController` property which is your controller

```
guard let navCon = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, 
      let controller = navCon.topViewController as? ListTableViewController else { fatalError("Segue wasn’t set right") }
```

---

Anyway, I would suggest you don’t use segues and create your `UINavigationController` with embedded controller programmatically

Comment: Thank you so much dear Robert